# How can I apply a hover transformation to a CSS background image without transforming the content?

Tags: html, css, hover, css-transforms

I am trying to apply [this sort of overlay effect](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_overlay.asp) to an background image on hover. However I only want this transformation to apply to the background image, not the text or other content in the div.

Here's my code at the moment without any hover effect - the approach in the w3schools link above doesn't seem suitable:

```css
.background-image {
  background: url('http://placehold.it/350x200') no-repeat center;
}

.about-text {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="col-md-6 text-center background-image overlay">
  <div class="about-text">
    <p>Some descriptive text here. Blah blah blah.</p>
    <p class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-primary" href=""> Button </a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you want ? [See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/438seypn/4/)

**HTML**

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="col-md-6 text-center background-image overlay">
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="about-text">
    <p>Some descriptive text here. Blah blah blah.</p>
    <p class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-primary" href=""> Button </a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**
    .background-image {

```
  height: 200px;
}
.background { 
  background: url('http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/350/200/1') no-repeat center;
  position: absolute; width: 350px; height: 200px; 
}

.about-text {
  color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    width: 350px;
 transition: all 0.5s;
}

.background-image:hover .about-text { background: #333}
```

Comment: Perfect, that is exactly what I was trying to achieve, and much simpler than I anticipated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, I imagine it's something like this:

```css
.background-image {
  background: url('http://placehold.it/350x200') no-repeat center;
}

.overlay {
  transition: background-position 250ms ease-in-out;
}

.overlay:hover {
  background-position: center -100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="col-md-6 text-center background-image overlay">
  <div class="about-text">
    <p>Some descriptive text here. Blah blah blah.</p>
    <p class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-primary" href=""> Button </a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes - that's almost exactly what I'm after, thanks, however I'm trying to do a fade-in overlay which requires opacity change... and struggling to get my head round it.